# Mount/Use controller in console

Tags: symfony, silex

In a Silex console command I want to perform a sub-request on a controller route. Unfortunately routes don't seem to be imported when executing a command by default.
I always get the following error:

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route "xyz_subject_method" as
>   such route does not exist

Therefore I tried to mount the defining controller from within my Console class by using `$this->mount('/prefix', Controller::mount($this))` inside the Console constructor. This has no effect.

Is there any way to access controllers *directly* from a console command?

Comment: Yes of course. What about using dependency injection?

Comment: @JimPanse How would I solve this with DI? I've searched for a solution but only found conflicting answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mounting a controller inside the Console constructor you need to flush the controller collection by using `$this->flush();`

So mounting the controller should look like this:

```
$this->mount('/prefix', Controller::mount($this));
$this-flush();
```